# Can a Karnaugh map be solved in more than one way?

Tags: boolean-algebra

So I understand for doing a simplification by a K Map I should group my 1's (or even 0's) in $2^n$ elements, always trying to grup as much elements as possible. And I can group even adjacent elements ....

So let's say, is it correct if I perform 5 different groupings, even if any *5th* grouping isn't following the grouping the most possible elements rule?

Comment: You mean can you group 2 pairs of adjacent 2 elements, instead of grouping all 4 together?

Comment: Yes, that would be way of my question. From my understanding, it would not be wrong BUT it wouldn't give an optimal solution.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be any different. But if you build a system on that basis, it will be susceptible to [static logic hazards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(logic)).